# How much will studying magic in an academy cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, pricing, eberron, economy

Here is why I ask this question:

I want to create a wizard character that goes to the best magic school in the Eberron settings (which I will also be playing in): the Arcanix. But, I want to say in his background that he has a large debt that he accrued to pay for his studies.

I wanted to find how much it could cost to study to become a wizard level 1, but I found nothing.

**How much will studying magic in an academy cost?**

Comment: See also [Is there a place to find the pricing for (non-magical) things not mentioned in the PHB?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143292/is-there-a-place-to-find-the-pricing-for-things-not-mentioned-in-the-phb-non-m)

Comment: Does it *have* to be a cash debt? Owing favors to a benefactor might be easier for your DM to work into the plot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I didn't find any references to costs of higher education, so I'm going to do a real world comparison.

### Disclaimer

[As it's well said in @NautArch's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150212/how-much-will-studying-magic-in-an-academy-cost/150222#150222), this is not an accurate comparison, and I fully agree that a fantasy world is going to have a lot of nuances that will vary the prices of products, like guild based economy where competition doesn't exist and holds prices, for instance. But I still think it can serve as a reference to how much things cost in a more broader sense. The more you compare what things cost between them the more sense you can have of how much money (meaning coin) itself is worth.

**It's impossible to find the real price of a product or service that exists only in fiction.** There is no real way to compare it with something real moreso when the used coin itself is not real. **This is not me saying "This is the accurate price"**. It's just "If X costs Y in our world, and Z in fantasy, you can compare it and have a clue of how much something is worth". Maybe the result is outrageous, maybe it makes sense to you. In the end it's fiction, so **take this only as a way, or a tool to decide on the cost, nothing else**. In the end prices are subjective. Economy is very complex, and in a roleplaying game, **every product and every coin is put in circulation by the authority of the DM**.

### A little bit of math

A spiced apple cinnamon wine bottle, which is likely a cider, costs 5 silvers in Eberron. ([Got the reference from here](http://eberronunlimited.wikidot.com/eberron-food-and-drink))

In Madrid a bottle of cider costs around 3€.

In Madrid higher education costs an average of 1,609€ a year.

Then we do a rule of three.

0.5 [gp cost of cider in Eberron] * 1,609 [Higher education in Madrid] / 3 [Cost of cider in Madrid] = The average cost of higher education in Eberron should go around **268.16 GP per year**. This is more or less the cost of a coach with a horse, so it's pretty expensive.

Take in mind this is a rough approximate for an average university cost. Values could vary depending on market conditions. But I think it's a good measure of the basic cost, you could go up from there.

Probably magic schools in Eberron take a lot less students, which means increased prices, so you could get a more accurate price if you could know how many students does a magic school in Eberron have vs how many students does the average college or university have.

Since we got the cost of studying in Harvard from the answer user @Phillip gave us before (67,580$) we can use this method to do a similar comparison with the cider bottle in USA (around 5$ for a litre) giving us a total of **6,758gp a year**.

### DM controls the economy

But definitely, this is just another perspective and more of a thought experiment. [@NautArch's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150212/how-much-will-studying-magic-in-an-academy-cost/150222#150222) is the most practical in regards to the game. The DM decides the value of money and controls all the economy, so the DM should decide.

Comment: Considering higher education in Europe tends to be heavily subsidized, I gotta think the US figure is a closer analogy.

Comment: @sirtechspec why do you think eberron is more like the US?

Comment: You don't need to use USA numbers but you should use un-subsidized numbers. In France, it's very easy to go to a public university and only pay around 200€ per year. The real price, though, is closer to 8 or 10k € (that's the price it costs to the state). So even in Spain, I doubt that 1,609€ represents anything close to the real price of a year in uni.

Comment: It's an average, represents a middle ground between public (heavily funded) and private (not funded at all). Still you can do this operation which whatever price you deem right. That's the magic of economy, the right price is subjective.

Comment: What make you use cider as a baseline? If the choice was arbitrary, it's worth noting the price of a single item (relative to other items) can vary greatly based on a number of factors. Maybe the ingredients can only grow in few or far away places, there are many similar products available, the production is much easier or cheaper due to the existence or abundance of other things or maybe there are cultural or historic reasons affecting demand.

Comment: Do you have a source for your "spiced apple cinnamon wine bottle" price figure?

Comment: it also depends on the type of economy, governing forces, and demand in magic schools in the area. All of those things are governed by the DM.

Comment: @Jasper, yes I got it from an Eberron Wiki page, now linked in the answer.

Comment: @NotThatGuy It's absolutely arbitrary, and yep, everything you say it's true. Just consider it's oversimplified for the sake of pragmatism.

Comment: Oddly, there is no source confirming that cost is from a rulebook. :( It also references that those costs need to be converted and are 'old' or something. it's not clear, and the links are dead.

Comment: @NautArch If anyone can find me a rulebook confirmed source of prices for eberron with a product similar to cider, I can go over again. But is it really necessary?

Comment: It's up to you, but it is integral to your calculations. If that's off, then the calculation is as well. I still think the bigger issue is in the assumptions on eberron wizard school pricing being equivalent to Harvard's current pricing.

Comment: If it seems like I'm aiming to give a concrete price maybe this answer is really off the rails... Maybe I need to maul the point about this being merely a tool and not a concrete answer.

Comment: I think this just highlights that all of the pricing for mundane equipment and services in 5E is ridiculously arbitrary and nonsensical and probably just made up on the spot. If you try to extrapolate anything from existing pricing in order to build out a bigger model like this, it all just collapses.

Comment: FWIW, total cost of going to Oxford University today, for someone from the US is roughly half of the cost of that same person going to Harvard. On the other hand, because of the setting, a more comparable time of going to Oxford might be the 12-1400's, and at that time, the cost was entirely supported by the government and the church, with little to no cost to students, *but* it also took 6 years for a bachelors, and up to *18 years* for a higher degree.

Answer (score 33):

## It's going to be up to the DM

5e doesn't cover schooling costs for Wizards, but I'll leave it to others better versed in D&D lore to see if it's covered in other editions and, if so, to update the cost to match 5e.

But it's okay that there isn't a RAW answer here. Your question is more about creating a background hook, not about a mechanical need.

### DM and player should work together on this

As you've described, this is to wanting to create a plot hook about having a debt that can be used in the game. Which is awesome!

The DM is going to need to consider the rate at which you'll accumulate wealth and how that ties into your debt so that they can build a narrative around this hook for you.

Determining what debt amount is going to be a driver is the difficult part here. The DM will need to consider the following:
- How much loot they expect to hand out regularly
- Is there magic item economy and how prevalent are magic items (that can be sold for gold.)
- Will downtime activities be available to make additional money

The above can help guide a DM in looking at how quickly their PCs will accumulate wealth and combine that with how they'd like the plot hook to work. Utilizing that information along with how long they want this hook to continue for will help guide the DM in coming up with a sum that works for the story.

Just creating a straight value (say 1000gp) that seems like a lot may not actually be so if wealth accumulation is faster because of the some of the levers above. This is ultimately a relative value, but only the DM knows how wealth and accumulation of wealth is going to work for the PCs in their game.

### Beware of false equivalences

They can opt to pull data from modern high education, but that is not necessarily an equivalent. Education costs have been variable historically and geographically.

**Rather than trying to create an equivalence that isn't necessarily accurate, it's better to create a number that works for the story.**

Comment: I like it, and hope the OP and their DM take that approach.

Comment: I definitely agree with this because (as nick pointed out) there are already background features that incorporate the concept of debt.  Generally, even having a number is not really a good way to go... because the whole point of this is to have an RP hook... and it should be momentous when it's taken care of.  It should not be "oh, finally got the exact amount when we sold the copper tea set, done".

Comment: FWIW, and in support of your point on false equivalences: Modern higher education has tripled in cost over the last 30 years when adjusted for inflation. (Source, The Economist).   In otherwords: the cost per credit hour/year in 1989 was 1/3 of what it is now (and that includes correction for inflation).

Answer (score 15):

[As the answer by nick012000 points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150212/how-much-will-studying-magic-in-an-academy-cost/150215#150215), RAW your character has no obligation to start their game with a debt. But let's say you really want to burden your character with such a student loan for RP purposes.

One approach to eyeballing this could be to assume the academy operates at cost and uses the fees paid by the students to finance the lifestyles of the students as well as the faculty.

We can use the [lifestyle expenses table](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Expenses#content) for that purpose. If we assume that living on campus has a "Modest" lifestyle cost at 1gp/day (it's a fine university and campus life is expensive), the faculty get paid enough to have a "Wealthy" lifestyle at 4gp/day (they are the best wizardry teachers you can get, so you should give them proper lodgings), and you assume a student-to-faculty ratio of 7 to 1 ([just like on real-world Ivy-League schools](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-s-a-good-student-to-faculty-ratio-for-a-college-4134430)) you have a cost of (7gp + 4gp)/7 = **1.57gp** per day to cover the lifestyle costs of the student and the faculty members who teach them.

However, they also need to pay for maintaining the building and for teaching material, specifically all the material components the students need for training. The material costs of most 1st level spells the students would learn would be negligible. But just as with any university, we can also assume that some higher-level research goes on at the academy which requires more expensive components. So let's round our 1.57gp up to **2gp/day.**

---

Another way to approach this could be to use a real-world anlogue. [Studying at Harvard with room and board costs $67,580 a year](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/123014/what-harvard-actually-costs.asp). That's very close to the median household income in the US. Assuming that a median household has "Comfortable" living expenses and doesn't accumulate wealth, we also arrive at about **2gp/day**. This should be about what the average upper-middle-class Eberron citizen could *afford* to pay for studying at an university.

---

An [Eberron year](http://eberronunlimited.wikidot.com/eberron-calendar) has 13 months with 28 days each, or 364 days. So with a cost of 2gp per day you would end up with a student debt of **728gp per year**.

---

Comment: Could be less if the schools take a summer break or something

Comment: Is there a reason why modern American schooling is an equivalent for Eberron? Our education costs are far different than other countries - and historically they've changed greatly as well.

Comment: @NautArch Well if you want to be in a large debt for the character background it would be the best schooling costs to use.  If costs were lower, most characters would be able to pay off their debt after a dungeon or two.

Comment: @Nathan Sure, but then you're just making something up. You can use that, but if you can't support why that system is applicable, then it's not as helpful.

Comment: @NautArch, the mathematics of the answer doesn't change if you change the real-world base cost.  Just reapply the same formula from the different starting point, and you'll reach an answer equivalent to that starting point.  *ANY* comparison between a fictional world, with a fictional currency, and the real world is going to be every bit as arbitrary as your chosen starting point.  Just pick the starting point you thing is appropriate, and work from there.

Answer (score 15):

### Hirelings

One quick and easy way to estimate this is with Hirelings (PHB 159). The chart indicates that a Skilled hireling costs 2gp/day, and the text says this:

> Skilled hirelings include anyone hired to perform a service that involves a proficiency (including weapon, tool, or skill): a mercenary, artisan, scribe, and so on. The pay shown is a minimum; some expert hirelings require more pay.

Presumably your elite university averages out to around 3 to 5, with the extra skill required. So, superficially, 3-5gp per day times 364 days per [Eberron year](http://eberronunlimited.wikidot.com/eberron-calendar) times several years of study gets you into the thousands of gold pretty easily. Don't forget to include interest payments and fees.

There are also some great world building opportunities here. You could restructure this and say that the government covers most of tuition. Or that nobles overpay for their children and sycophants to learn cantrips. Or that nobles pay outrageously for spellcasting services. Any of these could mean no financial debt, which is fine because

### D&D: Finance Edition is *boring*

Since you're already on PHB 159, keep reading the next section, *Spellcasting Services*. It explicitly mentions that spellcasters, particularly of higher levels, may ask for services or favors instead of currency.

The point is debts do not necessarily have to be monetary.

Consider what a wizarding school might want from a magically trained individual that would be harder to acquire for someone mundane. Here are some more interesting, plot-hook-esque options:

- In-kind services teaching a semester or three of *Cantrips for Cads* and *Remedial Rituals*
- 10 levels worth of previously lost/unknown written spells for the archives
- Magical reagents such as crystal spheres or valuable gems
- Oddly specific magical reagents, like a forked piece of metal attuned to a particular plane for casting *Plane Shift*
- Right of first bid on found magic items
- Requirement to help anyone bearing the Academy's sigil with anything they may ask for
- Favors like helping the forgetful headmaster recover his lost *Leomund's Secret Chest*
- Performing flashy parlor tricks as part of the annual recruitment drive and pep rally

Note that several of these provide good options for player turnabout. If you teach some students, maybe they owe you a favor. If you bear the guild's sigil, then maybe the alumni network can help out once in a while, possibly in return for future favors.

Comment: This is excellent; by turning the obligation into *plot hooks*, you get more out of it.

Comment: The more I review the answers to this question the more I like your answer. (And anyway, who got the idea that importing student loan debt into an RPG was a fun thing to do?)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thanks! I'm not sure who wants to do stuff like loan debt, double-entry bookkeeping, or actuarial tables in D&D, but if it is fun for them, I can't say it's objectively wrong. I can say that I personally wouldn't be very interested in that game (but I'd try it once anyway).

Comment: I should have smiliey faced that comment.  The *favor economy* is IMO particularly suited to RPG's and fits into this party of your answer: *The point is debts do not necessarily have to be monetary*

Answer (score 4):

Per G. Moylan's [suggestion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150212/how-much-will-studying-magic-in-an-academy-cost/150220#comment386794_150215), you can refer to the debt table in [Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wgte) (page 11, Why Do You Need
200 Gold Pieces?).

> Establishing a debt requires collaboration and approval by both player
>   and DM. Work together to develop the details: who is blackmailing you?
>   What’s this secret society? What’s the story behind the magic item
>   you’ve pawned, and what sort of item is it? As a player, you present
>   ideas but the DM has final approval.

The table seems to suggest that all of the backgrounds require you to raise 200 gold pieces within a month.

To state this explicitly: the academy costs exactly as much as the plot dictates.

Comment: I think they just say 200gp as an example, same with the reasons in the quoted text

Answer (score 4):

As DnD is set primarily in a medieval fantasy world, using the costs of going to a middle ages university seems like a good idea.

Universities back than did not function the way most universities work today.

1. They were privately owned, for profit universities. They existed to make a profit and pay for the livelihoods of the professors who ran them.
2. you didn't pay a tuition to the school, you paid your professors individually. Which makes the yearly costs a little hard to calculate as it depended on what classes you were taking. The prices were set for the various course by the University, with classes for valuable degrees (like medicine) costing princely sums while classes for useless degrees (art) cost very little.

The university of Barcelona was calculated (by a professor in the 1300s) to charge a princely sum of 100 Lyre (roughly equivalent to the British pound) per year for a 5 year degree in medicine.

If we than compare the cost of university to other things during the middle ages such as unskilled labor, we can get a useful thing to judge what the price of attending a university of magic should approximate.

Unskilled laborers made 2 pence a day or 2 pounds a year in the 1300s (working 240 days a year). Meaning it takes 50 years of unskilled labor to pay for 1 year of university education.

Unskilled Hirelings (in dnd 5e) cost 2 sp a day, and assuming your average unskilled laborer works the same number of days per years as an medieval unskilled laborer your average cost per year should be around 2 sp * 240 days/per year * 50 years common labor/ year school =  48gp * 50 years = **2400 gp per year of schooling.** If it takes 5 years of study to become a "graduate" than that is a debt of 12000 gp.

Sources: University Records and Life in the Middle Ages (1944), Lynn Thorndike.
https://thehistoryofengland.co.uk/resource/medieval-prices-and-wages/

Now we could instead have used a modern day for profit university and the price of a bushel of wheat. To calculate the cost of attending a university in Eberon but comparing medieval economies to modern day economies is hard because we place a different value on everything.

The equivalent value of a pound from medieval Europe to modern day currency is hard to calculate:

- if we were to just look at what commodities a pound could buy in the
  1300s than each pound is only worth $997.0
- if we look at the amount of labor a single pound could purchase than
  each pound is worth $18,981.
- If we look at the equivalent income value of each pound (What your
  equivalent income would be if you made 1 pound a year) than each pound is worth $37,454.
- If we look at the economic share of a pound (relative worth
  divided by the periods GDP) than a pound is worth $413,875

Which shows that any comparisons between one economic system and another are going to be very problematic, and prone to inaccuracies, therefore my suggested sum of 2400 gp per year should not be in any way considered an accurate market value for the yearly costs of attending a school of Magic on Eberron.

https://measuringworth.com/calculators/ukcompare/

Answer (score 3):

While there are no explicit rules to cover the cost of an academy, there is a pretty obvious approximation that relies only on in-game numbers, not tenuous comparisons to our modern world: the **Training downtime activity**.  Do note there are two versions of this rule: one in the Player's Handbook (PHB; 250 gp, 250 days) and one in Xanathar's Guide to Everything (XGE; 25 gp per week, 10 weeks minus intelligence modifier).  How many years it takes depends on your world.  But if you want a suggested number, a Level 1 wizard has a total of about 20 unique skills/features if you add them all up (I considered all the simple weapons a single skill).  While you cannot normally gain these skills/features through Training during downtime, I think it is reasonable to use it as a reference.

- PHB then gives you **365 gp per year tuition for 14 years**.
- XGE (assuming flat rate independent of intelligence modifier - likely what the academy would charge) then gives you **1,300 gp per year tuition for 3 or 4 years**, depending on the wizard's INT.

I feel like the XGE rules are the most reasonable here for a Level 1 wizard.

Approaching the math from another angle yields similar results.  If students pay 1 gp/day for a Modest Lifestyle (PHB Expenses) and pay 2 gp/day for access to the academy's masters (Skilled Labor, from PHB Expenses), that adds to 1,095 gp/year.  A Level 1 wizard has about 450 gp in equipment (mostly in the spellbook: 50 gp with six level 1 spells in it, each of which costs 50 gp to add to the spellbook).  Spread that out over 3 years, add in some miscellaneous school supplies, and you quickly find yourself very close to the 1,300 gp/year we got from XGE Training.

Answer (score -5):

**Nothing. They owe no debts.** Under the Rules As Written, the starting gear of a PC is determined by their Class and Background, and this includes their starting money.

For a Sage Wizard, like a character who attended a wizard academy likely would be, their starting equipment would be as follows:

> - (a) a quarterstaff or (b) a dagger
> - (a) a component pouch or (b) an arcane focus
> - (a) a scholar’s pack or (b) an explorer’s pack
> - A spellbook
> - A bottle of black ink, a quill, a small knife, a letter from a dead colleague posing a question you have not yet been able to answer, a
>     set of com m on clothes, and a belt pouch containing 10 gp
>     A single Trinket, rolled on or chosen from the Trinket table on p. 160-161 of the PHB

Since they start off with a positive balance of gold, and there are no options for them to take on a debt in the Trinket table or the Flaws or Bonds of their Background, they would not owe any debts for their time at wizard school - presumably, if they ever owed any such debts, they would have already paid them off.

**However, there is one exception:** in the Ravnica setting, members of the Orzhov Syndicate (with the Orzhoc Representative Background) can take the following Bond: "The unbearable weight of my debt has driven me to desperation." A GM might be willing to allow you to take it with other Backgrounds, as well.

Comment: Note: Wayfinder's Guide does suggest owing a debt as part of a potential character backstory

Comment: Based on the actual real life, you can be owing a debt and have money on you, so the argument is invalid.
plus you actually don't answer the question at all

Comment: Also just because you have a positive balance of funds doesn't mean you don't owe money elsewhere. See Han Solo from Star Wars

Comment: @Rorp Generally, you can't do things the game says you can. This answer was based on RAW, and since the game doesn't say you can start with a debt, you can't. I also edited the answer to add the exception I found in, as well.

Comment: OP is specifically building a backstory around this, I see no reason why they can't do that. While you don't 'start' with a debt RAW, wanting to have one for a backstory hook is totally reasonable.

Comment: Given that the book explicitly encourages the creation of custom backgrounds, I think that you may want to support your answer some other way. "Only one background allows this so the RAW says no" is not really tenable when the book allows you to freely create backgrounds at DM discretion.

Comment: @Rorp based on real life in countries that provide free education (at primary, secondary and tertiary education) you don't accumulate a debt for being educated to university level. I come from one such country.

Comment: FYI The backgrounds Criminal/Spy, Urban Bounty Hunter, Guild Artisan/Merchant and the tabaxi race all reference having and being in debt as well. "*I'm trying to pay off an old debt I owe to a generous benefactor*" and "*You are always in debt since you spend your gold on lavish parties and gifts for friends*" for example. So there seems to be more than one exception.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose That use of debt in the backgrounds are not necessarilyl monetary.  JoeL Harmon covers that nicely in his answer.  And if we go back to a literal translations of the Lord's Prayer, it's "forgive us our debts" which contextually had as much to do with social debts and debts of honor as it did any debt of property or coin. (Hence some renditions of that prayer being "trespasses" ... but I am way off topic now.   The term "owe a debt" is not confined to money.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Correct (though my second example you'd have to stretch pretty far to say that doesn't explicitly mean money) that doesn't really change my point that more than one background allows a PC to acquire debt. Since "debt" can be ambiguous that would mean acquiring a money debt is written option for these backgrounds, even if it's not restricted to coin only.